# Сервлет для web приложения

Tags: java, mysql, веб-программирование, servlet, jdbc

Есть БД MySQL с таблицей mytable (column ID, column NAME), пишу приложение для вывода в файл HTML результатов выполнения хранимых процедур (вывести таблицу, вставить и удалить значение)
Написал класс для работы с бд:

```
public class Main {

private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
private static Connection con;

private Main() throws Exception {
    try {
        Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        con = getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Не удалось загрузить класс драйвера!");
    }
}



public List<User> getUsers(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    List users = new ArrayList();
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try (CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{CALL sel}")) {
        boolean hadResults = stmt.execute();

        while (hadResults) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet()) {

                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    int id = rs.getInt("ID");
                    String name = rs.getString("NAME");
                    users.add(new User(id, name));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        stmt.close();
        return users;

    }
}

public static void ins_upd (Connection con, int id, String name) {

    try(CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{CALL ins_upd(?,?)}")){
        stmt.setInt(1, id);
        stmt.setString(2, name);
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public static void del (Connection con, int ID) {
    try(CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{CALL del(?)}")){
        stmt.setInt(1, ID);
        stmt.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

и сущность user

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class User {
private static ArrayList<User> users;
private int id;
private String name;



public User (int id, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
public static ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String toString() {
    return id + " " + name;
}

}
```

Насколько я понимаю осталось написать сервлет для связи запросов клиента и ответов сервера. Не знаю как мне вывести методы в классе Main в HTML форму и соединить эту форму с сервлетом? Пока всё что в севрлете есть :

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
}
}
```

Comment: dispatcher получен, теперь надо с помощью него задиспатчить запрос. `diapatcher.forward(req, resp);` (есть ещё вариант `diapatcher.include(req, resp);`). Но это не всё. Так Вы только отдадите свой index.html клиенту. Остальное тема для книжки про сервлеты. Почитайте макулатурку.

Comment: Хорошо, вроде нашёл информацию